# WebView loadUrl(localFile) - handle unsupported file type case

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a WebView which loads a local file like this:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///data/data/com.comp.android.client/files/mycache/DA8B436‌​C7534E54840D62E28A2EB394‌​188990236.hrt");
```

When then WebView knows the file extension then the file is rendered and is visible.

However, when the file type is unknown to the WebView then the WebView stays white and nothing gets rendered. How do I get notified that the file loading failed, and the WebView will not display the file I am telling it to display?

I tired onReceivedError but that does not fire, only when the content is downloaded from a network I assume which is not the case here. Also looked at onJsAlert as well without any luck.

So can the WebView tell me that the file is not supported or that it can't display it?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the file located? In your directory?

Answer (score 0):

I once wrote a simple browser for myself and `onReceivedError()` can be fired each time it failed to load a network or local URL (either file-not-exist or access permission case).

And generally browser will try to show the content of the local file regardless of ASCII or binary content. i.e. if the file type is unknown then wenkit engine renders it as text in a HTML document. Showing a blank page without any error is the scenario I did not encountered...